# Visiting after several minutes page getting slow

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application which is served over HTTPS.

The problem I am facing is if I navigate from any browser while using and revisiting the browser it's taking more time to load.

How to resolve this?

```
window.location.reload()
```

Rather than this.

Any solution available.

1. localstorage
2. cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use service worker and PWA configurations if you have js and CSS to be cached at the user end.

PWA will not stop the process of loading css and js and other files again and again.  That will lead to faster page load speed